# Converting object of latlngs to google.map.LatLng object for polygon build

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a javascript object of latlng values as defined below that gets pushed to a google maps creation script

```
var lat1 = '51.0001';
        var lng1 = '52.0001';
        var lat2 = '61.0001';
        var lng2 = '62.0001';
        google_map_item.coordinates = [
            new polygonLatLng(lat1,lng1),
            new polygonLatLng(lat2,lng2)
        ];

    google_map_items.push(google_map_item);

    function polygonLatLng(lat,lng){
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
    }
```

As you can see the google_map_item.coordinates object is basically just a couple of points, I understand this isn't the full polygon but I've hard coded some simple values to just try and get the script to work before using dynamic ones.

The object google_map_items gets pushed to the map creation script as below:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {       

        var longitude = google_map_items[0].lat;
        var latitude = google_map_items[0].lon;
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(longitude, latitude);

        var zoomlevel = parseInt(google_map_items[0].zoomlevel);

        var myOptions = {
          zoom: zoomlevel, 
          center: center,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        for(i = 0; i < google_map_items.length; i++) {
          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(google_map_items[i].lat, google_map_items[i].lon);
          bounds.extend(latlng);

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            icon: "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter_withshadow&chld=" + (i + 1) + "|FF8888|000000",
            zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              $(".surgery").removeClass("highlighted");
              $("#surgery-" + (i + 1)).addClass("highlighted");
            }
          })(marker, i));

        }

        if (google_map_items.length >1 ) { map.fitBounds(bounds); }

                //check if area to add to map
                //if(google_map_items.coordinates){
                var surgeryArea;

                var areaCoords = [

                ];

                    surgeryArea = new google.maps.Polygon({
                        paths: google_map_item.coordinates,
                        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                        strokeOpacity: 0.4,
                        strokeWeight: 2,
                        fillColor: "#FF0000",
                        fillOpacity: 0.35,
                        clickable: true
                    });

                    // add an event listener
                    google.maps.event.addListener(surgeryArea, 'click', function() {
                        this.setMap(null);
                    });

                    surgeryArea.setMap(map);

                //}

      });
```

There is an empty obecjt for areaCoords that needs to be built ussing the new google.maps.LatLng constructor for each point inside the google_map_item.coordinates object. My knowledge of javascript object and array manipulation is not advanced enough to work out the syntax to pass this through so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of your coordinates:

```
    google_map_item.coordinates = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lat1),
        new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lat2)
    ];
```